# Marker doesn't load google maps,

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to load marker from database but those markers doesn't loaded. However if I try to load manually it's working.

my view view_file.php

```
  var map;
  function initialize(lt,lg) {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lg),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
      <?php foreach ($position as $row) { ?>
            $lat = $row['lat'];
            $longi = $row['longi'];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$longi);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
            })
        <?php } ?>
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize(-0.165343, 113.930935)">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

my controller map.php

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('maps');
}

function index(){
    $data['position']   =   $this->maps->marker();
    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('view_file', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

my model maps.php

```
function marker(){
    $post = $this->db->get('koor');
    return $post->result();
}
```

This code below is works (entered coordinate manually). controller are same like above.

```
var map;
  function initialize(lt,lg) {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lg),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    marker(-0.735467, 110.521677);
    marker(1.549480, 116.124705);
    marker(-2.558367, 115.179880);
  }

   function marker(lt,lg){
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize(-0.165343, 113.930935)">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

I've tried to modified my code, searched similiar problem but nothing works, this is last shape of my code.

**UPDATE**

I've already solve this

```
 var map;
 function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-0.165343, 113.930935),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });
    var lat, longi, marker;
    <?php foreach ($position as $row) { ?>
        lat = <?php echo $row->lat ?>,
        longi = <?php echo $row->longi ?>,

        marker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longi);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: marker,
            map: map
        });
    <?php } ?>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
$lat = $row['lat'];
$longi = $row['longi'];
```

This is showing up in the javascript.
Make sure that it is going to be executed in php and not javascript.

The right code:

```
<?php
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $longi = $row['longi'];
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response,
ya it's my bad, I am already fix that as you and Saeed suggested me but the page doesn't load anything and nothing in browser console too.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var map;
  function initialize(lt,lg) {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lg),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

      var lat, longi;

      <?php foreach ($position as $row) { ?>

            lat = <?= $row->lat ?>;
            longi = <?= $row->longi ?>;
            marker(lat, longi);

        <?php } ?>
  }

  function marker(lt,lg){
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize(-0.165343, 113.930935)">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response,
ya it's my bad, I am already fix that as your suggested, but the map page is blank. Doesn't load anything and nothing in browser console log.

Comment: Are you sure `$row['lat']` and `$row['longi']` have correct value? please get `var_dump` and see values

Comment: I'm sure these are have correct value,

result of var_dumb
array(1) { ["position"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (2) { ["lat"]=> string(10) "-1.2544742" ["longi"]=> string(11) "116.8599428" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#24 (2) { ["lat"]=> string(9) "-1.258223" ["longi"]=> string(10) "116.860009" } } }

Comment: in your `var_dump` i see `$row` are `stdClass` so you must use `$row->lat` and `$row->longi`

Comment: now I got an error in browser console, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var.
At least the error is showing up. haha

Comment: unfortunatly it's still doesn't work, but thank you for helping me to this close. I'll post my answer if I get it work. :-D

Comment: Hi, I've already got the solution. I update the answer in my question above. thank for help me :D